# Java Timer Every X Seconds

Tags: java, timer, repeat

So, I basically need a command to run every 5 seconds, but the Timer doesn't work...
I tried so many different methods,
The only thing that works is the Thread.sleep(Milliseconds);
But that causes my whole game to stop working...
If I try using a timer, for example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hey");

            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.start();
```

How can I get this timer to fire correctly?

Comment: You have it set for 1000, which is 1 second, not 5.

Comment: Yes I know, but even if I set it to 5000 it still does the same thing

Comment: put it in a new thread and call sleep on that thread then the game wont stop working if you want this i can give you the answer

Comment: I will try that, and post another comment to tell you if it works or not

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should pair `java.util.Timer` with `java.util.TimerTask`

```
Timer t = new Timer( );
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Hey");

    }
}, 1000,5000);
```

1000 means `1 second delay` before get executed
& 5000 means will be `repeated every 5 seconds`.

To stop it , simply call `t.cancel()`